# How to display props and render on the view from component to another?

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys I am trying to render data from the stock search component into the Displadata component. However I am currently getting a type error and get an undefined message when I try to access the object. Could someone help me do this correctly?

Here is a sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-lake-8r8w8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the answer given by gdh works. In addition you can use optional chining like {this.props.results?.BTC?.USD} which is a new JS feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data comes from API, initially the `this.props.results.BTC` will be undefined and **eventually** receives the data.

So instead of directly rendering `this.props.results.BTC.USD` in your render method,

**Do this**

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.dataResults()}
        {this.props.results && this.props.results.BTC && this.props.results.BTC.USD}
      </div>
    );
```